# Flashlight that doesn't need permissions

Tags: android

What is a good flashlight for Android that doesn't track a user, and doesn't require any unusual privileges?

Edit: I just want to know that simplest way to get a good safe flashlight

Comment: If you're willing to try custom roms, every custom rom I've used has had their own 'flashlight' built into the system that doesn't require any permission.

Comment: Also Android 5.0 has a flashlight option built in. Just swipe down from the top for the quick settings menu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've given not much criteria, so there're not that many requirements to meet. But first, helping you to help yourself: See [How to search the Play Store by permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20619/16575) on our sister-site, and then give [StripSearch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hasslefixes.stripsearch) a try :)

Now specifically for your torch:

- [Simple Torch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.volsa.torch) just asks for flashlight and camera, no network. Camera is sometimes required to adjust intensity of flash light AFAIK.
- [Torch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.swijaya.galaxytorch): same here (plus "draw over other windows", but again no network)
- [QuickTorch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yoavst.quicktorch): just camera and "draw over …"
- [Flashlight Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.bleeding182.flashlight): just camera and "draw over"

All these apps are smaller than 200 kB `.apk` size (which is another indicator they're not doing anything "strange").

Comment: It takes 200kB to make a flashlight?

Comment: @immibis Read again: "smaller than". *Simple Torch* is just about 40kB – which deems correct for an app with that "job" and no graphics. Put some graphic in (e.g. for a nice, but not strictly necessary "start screen"), and you easily get 100kB+. // It might be easier to check your "Quick Settings" (at least with my devices running CyanogenMod, they have a torch option) – but I'm not sure if that's a standard (stock) or CM-specific as I have no stock ROMs anymore ;)

Answer (score 5):

As you have asked for minimal permissions, it would be good if they are opensource also. Install [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/) in your Android Phone. It can be considered a OpenSource Apps PlayStore. It contains all the apps that are open source and Search for **Torch** or **FlashLight**.

Have found some apps : **Search Light**, **Torch (LED Torch)**, **Torch (FlashLight)**, **Open Flashlight** and more which have very minimal permissions 1 or 2 and some of them are between 20 - 25KB in size.

If you have a phone that doesn't have camera and Flashlight, there is an app called **Mr.White** which increases white light display to the maximum and lets you use it as Torch.

Answer (score 0):

Swipe down from the top of your phone's screen.  You should see a couple icons (I see Wi-Fi, Location, Sound, Screen Rotation and Bluetooth), and in the top right corner there's an icon that looks like a pencil.  If you touch that, you should see more icons, one of which is a flashlight.